# cant figure how to sum nested id tables

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
LEVEL_01   LEVEL_02    LEVEL_03 
---        ---         ---
10010      10030       30010
10010      10040       30030
10010      10040       30040
10020      20010       20080
10020      10040       20080
10020      10040       20090
10021      20020       40000
```

and a table with amounts of the last level

```
id         amount
---     -------------
30010      100.00
30030      190.00
30040      800.00
30040      700.00
40000      250.00
20080      320.00
20090      500.00
```

What I need is to show sum data from the three levels, grouping / nesting levels like:

```
10010->10030->30010
10010->10040->30030
10010->10030->30040
-------------------
10010=sum(30010)+sum(30030)+sum(30040)=(100.00)+(190.00)+(1500.00) = 1790.00
10030=sum(30010)+sum(30040)=(100.00)+(1500.00) = 1600.00
30040=sum(30040) = 1500.00

(one record for LEVEL_10 thru LEVEL_03 and their relative sum.
```

Cant make it work. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do the sum with a join and then union the results for each level, like:

```
SELECT LEVEL_01, sum(amount) 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.level_03 = table2.id
GROUP BY LEVEL_01
UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL_02, sum(amount) 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.level_03 = table2.id
GROUP BY LEVEL_02
UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL_03, sum(amount) 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.level_03 = table2.id
GROUP BY LEVEL_03;
```

Comment: That method finally worked. I'd try to make it work in a single recursive sentence without success. I leave it as a task for some database guru. Thanks!

Comment: (I mean, my table sample shows 3 levels. The real case has 'n' levels).

Comment: I don't think recursion is going to work here because your data is already flattened to 'n' columns. For that you will need to dynamically build your sql for 1 to n columns and then submit the dynamically built sql. Not fun.